# httpd.worker binary was not created apache2.2.21

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

We complied the apache source code 2.2.21. we are able to run httpd and able to launch  the site.

But the problem is httpd.worker binary was not created. So How can I create httd.worker file to start server in thread based.

Sreenivas A.

Answer (score 1):

did you include the following in your configure line?

```
--with-mpm=worker
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..../configure --with-ldap --enable-mods-shared="all ssl ldap cache proxy authn_alias mem_cache file_cache authnz_ldap charset_lite dav_lock disk_cache " --with-mpm=worker..I used it but still not able to see http.worker file

Answer (score 0):

The binary `httpd.worker` is specific to RHEL-based distributions - you should not expect to have it (or any of their other distribution-specific customizations) when you compile from source.

When compiling from source with `--with-mpm=worker` as Mike mentioned, the `httpd` binary that's created uses the worker MPM.